# How can NSMutableArray add object using let in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

I created a NSMutableArray in swift using `let` and
when I add addObject in the mutableArray then it will add it even though I
used the `let` to assign a constant. Can anyone explain how `let` works in swift? If it doesn't allow you to add value in later then how is the following
code working?

```
let arr : NSMutableArray = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr.addObject(6)
println(arr)
```

Comment: `let` does not mean the array is not mutable. It means the variable `arr` cannot be set to any other object.

Comment: Can you please explain it with details? Because what I understand is let means a constant variable then how can we add an object to constant variable?

Comment: @ryancrunchi Actually the array is indeed not mutable when using let on it. Try it on a Swift array.

Comment: @Boon A NSMutableArray is mutable by definition... `var` or `let`, mutable is mutable. The difference is `let` cannot be reassigned to another object. But adding an object is not reassigning. That's why the code given works.

Comment: @ryancrunchi Understood, I am saying your statement only applies here because NSMutableArray is a reference type.  In the case of value type, let actually will not allow you to modify the value, such is the case with Swift array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

disclaimer: this answer only applies to NS type data structures, please see @Eric D's answer for the full picture

`let` when used with a class just means the variable cant be changed, eg, to another array. If you dont want the array to be editable, use a normal NSArray and not a mutable one

```
let arr : NSMutableArray = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr = [1,2,3,4,5] //error trying to assign to a let variable that has already been assigned

arr.addObject(6) //fine because we are not changing what is assigned to arr, but we are allowed to change the object that is assigned to arr itself
```

I think your understanding of what a constant variable is, is a bit too strict.

Comment: I wanted to know that if let means the variable that cannot changes then how can I change it using NSMuatbleArray?

Comment: let just means the value assigned to the variable cant change, not what ever is assigned to it cant change, for example you cant go, `let arr = [1,2,3]` then go `arr = [4,5,6]` cause thats assigning a completely different array to the variable

Comment: `arr.addObject` adds an object to the same variable, it does not assign a new array.

Comment: This is misleading - let doesn't just mean the variable cannot be changed.  A regular Swift array cannot have its value changed when assigned to a let variable.  Try arr[0] = 1 on it and see.

Comment: that is true @Boon, i wasnt thinking about the swift type array when answering, the other answer is correct

Answer (score 10):

Classes are *reference types*, and NSMutableArray is a class.

Foundation's NSMutableArray is different from Swift's Array: the latter is a *value type*.

If you create a constant NSMutableArray:

```
let ns: NSMutableArray = ["a", "b"]
```

then this works:

```
ns.addObject("c")
```

but this doesn't:

```
ns = ["d", "e"]   // nope!
```

because you can change the content of the reference but you can't change what is assigned to the constant.

On the other hand, with Swift's Array:

```
let sw: [String] = ["a", "b"]
```

the constant can't be changed because it's a value, not a reference.

```
sw.append("c")   // nope!
```

Doc: [Structures and Enumerations Are Value Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID88) and [Classes Are Reference Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID89)

Comment: I believe this answer is the right answer: "Foundation's NSMutableArray is different from Swift's Array: the latter is a value type."